# Please identify these capacitors and values

Tags: capacitor, identification

[image: photo of capacitors]

I'm tracing a circuit. What kind of capacitors are these yellow things? The upper one has markings of "105V 212K1", what does 212K1 stand for?  The lower one has markings of "335V 136K4", what does 136K4 stand for?

Comment: Hi, I've rolled-back your question to the previous version. You can't add more, *different* component types into *this* identification question. FYI, these are the current "[Component Identification Question Guidelines](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6710/component-identification-question-guidelines)". You can see that one component per question is stated there. (Your current question, with two similar capacitors, *probably* won't get rejected just because it has two components, as they are similar.)

Answer (score 6):

335 = 3.3 uF.  105 = 1.0 uF.

Those are dry tantalum electrolytics.  The end with the solid bar is the + (anode) connection.  The mitered corners of the upper decal also indicate the + end of a capacitor.

The lower capacitor was not intended to be an electrolytic; it was changed to one after the board design was completed.  That is why the solder pads are smaller, the decal is not mitered, and the part overhangs the courtyard (the sides of the decal).

Comment: I thought V means voltage. But what does the 212K1 and 136K4 mean?

Comment: @Jtl The letter after the value is usually a tolerance code. V is a rare one, but from what I can see it means -0%/+100%; in other words, the manufacturer guarantees that the measured capacitance will be no less than the rated value and no more than twice the rated value.

Comment: I suspect the 212K1 and 136K4 are date or lot codes, although they may encode something more useful.  [This guide](https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/electronic_components/capacitors/capacitor-codes-markings.php) looks informative, but be warned that it's just what came out at the top of a casual search.

Answer (score 4):

The top shows the value, 105 = 1uF the bottom shows Mfg date code/factory code  V  =2924  SMD size Tantalum  eg https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/avx-corporation/TAJA105K016RNJ/478-1649-1-ND/564681